# Loading UIWebView URL in other Viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uiwebview, preloading

I have a `UIWebView` which loads a local html file like this:

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html") {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }
```

This `WebView` is placed in my `SecondViewController`. My question is would it be possible to load the index.html upon launch in my Main `ViewController`?

The reason I'd like to do this is so the user won't have to view for the `WebView` to load when the user enters this View.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Just instantiate the `SecondViewController` upon launch and load the request in the web view. When push the `SecondViewController` later, the web view will already be loaded.